# get fixed value for android real time graph using GraphView library

Tags: android, real-time, android-graphview

I am trying to create a Real time graph view in android using GraphView library from [jjoe64GraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView). Now getting a real time graph with continuously changing Y axis values. Anyone can help me for change this real time graph with fixed value Y axis?

Thanks....